# AddListItem to list by using powershell

Tags: powershell, deployment

Is it possible to add list items to a list by using powershell commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - I'm not aware of a commandlet but it is easy to do using the Powershell commands agaist the object model. See [PowerShell-SharePoint: Add a list item](https://web.archive.org/web/20130814151152/http://blogs.flexnetconsult.co.uk:80/colinbyrne/2008/02/26/PowerShellSharePointAddAListItem.aspx) as an example (cross posted below for completeness). Just be aware that the site object still needs to be properly disposed as mentioned on the [SharePoint Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepoint/archive/2009/02/11/sharepoint-and-powershell-knowledge.aspx).

```
[void][System.reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint") 
 
$site    =     new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://teams.contoso.com")                                                        
$web     =    $site.rootweb                                                                                                
 
$list    =    $web.Lists["Announcements"]                                                                              
 
$newitem=    $list.items.Add()                                                                                                  
                                                                                                  
$newitem["Title"]=    "New CFO Appointed";                                                                                          
$newitem["Body"]=    "Our new CFO is Harry Varden, money still not recovered from previous appointee, legal action is ongoing";                                                                                          
$newitem["Expires"]=     [DateTime]::Now.AddDays(5)
 
$newitem.update() 
 
$web.Dispose()
$site.Dispose()
```